# JSTL refer variable from other variable

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I want to do something like this.

```
<c:set var="test_test">test</c:set>

<c:set var="test2">test_test</c:set>
```

Now I want to print test_test from test2

```
<c:out value ="${{test2}}"/>
```

This wont work but i want to do something like this.

Any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to initialize `test2` with the value of `test_test`. If so, you just need

```
<c:set var="test2" value="${test_test}"/>
```

which is roughly equivalent to the following Java code

```
Object test2 = test_test;
```

And if you want to display the content of `test2` (which is also the content of `test_test`), you just need

```
<c:out value="${test2}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the scope beforehand, then use the scope map directly wherin you pass the dynamic key using the brace notation. When using the `<c:set>` without explicitly specifying the `scope` attribute, it'll end up in the page scope which is as a map available by `${pageScope}`, so this should do for you:

```
${pageScope[test2]}
```

The request, session and application scope maps are available by `${requestScope}`, `${sessionScope}` and `${applicationScope}`.